# JAXB - How to unmarshall list of inherited types without declaring its element names or subclasses to the context

Tags: list, inheritance, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have list of elements where all its types are inherited from the same base class. Exists there a way to unmarshall it to list but get the objects of its derived types but wthout declaring all the subclasses or element names in the JAXB context?

I have in my real object structure around 150 sub classes, So I don't like to do this exercise of retyping a declaration if it can be retrieved automatically (hopefully).

I had tried "@XmlElements,@XmlSeeAlso, ,@XmlAnyElement, @XmlElementRef" but they all require to list either all the element names or class names.

My XML Structure:

```
<root>
   <Cat>...</Cat>
   <Dog>...</Dog>
   ...
</root>
```

My Class Structure:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Cat")
class Cat extends Animal ...

@XmlRootElement(name = "Dog")
class Dog extends Animal ...
```

My Root Class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")    
class Root {

   @XmlElement( ??? )
   private List<Animal> animals;
}
```

Using "@XmlElement**s**" would work but then I have to declare all the names which are already annotated on the class declaration. So not a good way for 150 subclasses.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")    
class Root {

  @XmlElements(value={
    @XmlElement(name="Cat", type=Cat.class),
    @XmlElement(name="Dog", type=Dog.class),
    ...
   })
  private List<Animal> animals;
}
```

"@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)" sounds nice but then I had to declare all the element names in the JAXB context which is also not a nice way.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")    
class Root {

  @XmlAnyElement(lax=true)
  private List<Object> animals;
}  

JAXBContext.newInstance("root:Cat:Dog:...");
```

"@XmlSeeAlso" would require to declare all the subclasses on the base class, which also not nice for me.

```
@XmlSeeAlso(Dog.class, Cat.class, ...)
public abstract class Animal ...
```

"@XmlElementRef" requires that I at least have to list all subclasses in the JAXB Context. Therefore also not really suitable for me.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "root")    
class Root {

  @XmlElementRef
  private List<Animal> animals;
}  

JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class, Dog.class, Cat.class, ...);
```

Any other hints?

Comment: You know you can pass in the packages instead of the classes via ***JAXBContext.newInstance("com.acme.foo:com.acme.bar" )***?   Not sure if that's any nicer for your 150 classes.

Comment: Thank you Scott, this is fine and would work. No I did'nt.